# Visual Studio to GitHub

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I want to put my code on a `Git repo` via Visual Studio,

[This](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart-vs2017) documentation says, rightclick on the master branch and press New local branch from.. but I do not have a master branch and the  button is disabled in my case:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible explanation is that you have created locally a Git repo, but have not created yet at least one commit.

Make sure you have added/committed your current modification in your local Git repo, and check again if the Visual Studio GUI is still displaying that option as disabled or enabled.

Comment: This was exactly my problem! Figured it out a minute ago tho, Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright it seem's like I really had to create the `master branch` by myself first. I thought this would be added when creating the repo:

I did the following:
Open the command line via right click on the Repo in Visual Studio

Type in: `git commit -m "Initial Commit"` where `Initial Commit` is the name of the commit.

The master branch was then created.

Comment: Exactly, the git init itself is not enough, and does not create branches yet. +1